# MainPage fails to Load properly

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have this code to set the Mainpage of my Application.

```
 public async Task  LoadMainPage()
    {
        try
        {
            
          signedin = Auth.IsUserSignedIn();
            if (signedin)
                registered = await Firestore.IsUserRegistered();
                
            if (!signedin)
            {
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
            }
            else if (signedin && !(registered))
            {
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new RegistrationPage());
            }
            else if (signedin && (registered))
            {
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new FlyoutPage1());
            }
           

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "OK"); }
    }
```

I am calling this method from App.Xaml.cs Onstart method

```
 protected  override  async void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();
        await LoadMainPage();

    }
```

the problem is when the Application is launched the Mainpage fails to Load Properly.
it appears only when i tap the triple line icon on my phone wait for some time and tap the application again to launch it.
the code for Firestore.IsUserRegistered is as below

```
 public async Task<bool> IsUserRegistered()
    {
       
       FirebaseFirestore collection = FirebaseFirestore.Instance;
        string email = FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser.Email;
        Android.Gms.Tasks.Task task = collection.Collection("User").WhereEqualTo("Email", email)
                .Limit(1).Get().AddOnSuccessListener(this);
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
          await  Task.Delay(100);
            if (isregistered ) break;
        }

        return isregistered;
    }
  public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
       
            var documents = (QuerySnapshot)result;
            isregistered = !documents.IsEmpty;
            
       
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged it?  Which if/else statement is executing?  Are there any exceptions?  Note that if the `MainPage` has not been assigned, then `App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert` will not work.

Comment: else if (signedin && (registered))
                {
                    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new FlyoutPage1());
                } this lifelese  is executing and mainpage is set to FlyoutPage1.i know this is happening  due to Task.Delay(100) in isUserRegistered() method .but i can't find a solution to this.

Comment: Are you positive an exception isn’t thrown?  Have you stepped through the constructor of Flyoutpage?

Comment: No Exception is not Thrown..As I have mentioned in my Post  the FlyoutPage appears only after i tap the triple line icon on my phone wait for some time and tap the blank page to launch it..The constructor of my Flyoutpage is public FlyoutPage1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           FlyoutPage.ListView.ItemSelected += ListView_ItemSelected;
           
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `await LoadMainPage();` to `OnResume()` just like [**Splash Screen**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen#create-a-splash-activity).

It said:

> The startup work is performed asynchronously in `OnResume`. This is necessary so that the startup work does not slow down or delay the appearance of the launch screen. When the work has completed, `SplashActivity` will launch `MainActivity` and the user may begin interacting with the app.